# Sequel - migration fails on one table

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I am trying to do the initial migration with dumped sequel migration from another DB. But I am still getting in the trouble in one table.

> /www/ruby2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sequel-4.46.0/lib/sequel/adapters/postgres.rb:195:in `async_exec': PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block (Sequel::DatabaseError)

In this table.

```
create_table(:utilization_disks, :ignore_index_errors=>true) do
  primary_key :id, :type=>:Bignum
  String :ip, :size=>64, :null=>false
  String :device, :size=>16
  Integer :read_ops
  Integer :write_ops
  Integer :read_kbytes
  Integer :write_kbytes
  DateTime :tstamp

  check Sequel::SQL::BooleanExpression.new(:>=,Sequel::SQL::Identifier.new(:read_ops), 0)
  check Sequel::SQL::BooleanExpression.new(:>=, Sequel::SQL::Identifier.new(:write_ops), 0)
  check Sequel::SQL::BooleanExpression.new(:>=, Sequel::SQL::Identifier.new(:read_kbytes), 0)
  check Sequel::SQL::BooleanExpression.new(:>=, Sequel::SQL::Identifier.new(:write_kbytes), 0)

  index [:id], :name=>:id, :unique=>true
  index [:ip], :name=>:index_utilization_disks_ip
  index [:tstamp], :name=>:index_utilization_disks_tstamp
end
```

It is Postgresql adapter, not able to find the problem. I can reproduce the error anytime. Also, I am trying to switch off the multi-thread mode.

```
Sequel.single_threaded = true
```

to be sure (this table is a part of bigger migration), that is not colliding somewhere.

If I migrate rest of database and try to add this table, it fails too. The other tables are almost similar.

Thanks for help

MP